# UITableViewCell Background Image - Ipad Development

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I would like to define a background like the attached image to my UITableViewCell. I’m trying that with the code below but without success.

```
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"teste1.png"]];
```

My UITableView is a grouped and static one. I've also tried to define tableView.backgroundcolor to clear color but also without success.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks,
Marcos

[image: UITableViewCellBackground]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"YOUR_IMAGE.png"]];
```

Comment: Don't forget that some of the `UITableViewCell` subviews do not have transparent background (e.g. `contentView` I think, which has an opaque white background, same with `textLabel` and `detailTextLabel` IIRC...) if you end up with white squares on your view, you need to set the relevant `backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]`

Comment: @PKCoder, with this solution the background image was not presented correct. Please check the screenshot the I've just uploaded

Comment: "PKCoder" thnx it's exactly what i want..:-)

Answer (score 0):

In the Apple's UITableViewCell documation, about backgroundView:

> The default is nil for cells in plain-style tables (UITableViewStylePlain) and non-nil for grouped-style tables UITableViewStyleGrouped). UITableViewCell adds the background view as a subview behind all other views and uses its current frame location.

So I don't think it would be a good idea to change the backgroundView for a grouped-style tables (which is happened your situation). Try to insert a new imageView above the back ground view:

```
UIImage *background = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:@"teste1"];
UIImageView *cellBackgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:background];
[cell insertSubview:cellBackgroundView aboveSubview:cell.backgroundView];
```

And don't forget to set the color to clear in all views may be above and block the background.

Comment: The backGroundColor of contentView of the cell which is above the backgroundView is not clear color by default, so remember to set it (and the background color for other views above the backgroundView) to  show the backGroundView. And you should also check with the image frame, to ensure it fits the cell's frame.

Answer (score 0):

I end up placing a UIButton inside the whole UITableViewCell area.